# How to trigger a specific AWS Lambda version from AWS Dynamodb Streams

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-streams

I have a dynamodb table that triggers a lambda function by enabling the Dynamodb streams. This was setup from the Dynamodb console.  I would however like to be able to point the trigger to a specific version/alias of the lambda function.  Most other AWS services allow you to specify the lambda ARN where you can tag on the version or alias at the end like arn:aws:lambda:::function::<version/alias>
However when adding a trigger to the dynamodb table , it only allows  you to select the lambda function name from a list and there seems to be no way to use a version/alias.
There also does not seem to be a CLI/api command to do the same.
Has anyone had any success doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can attach a different trigger to each alias we have for a Lambda function. In order to do this, we just have to go Lambda console, select our function, and create a new alias.

After the alias is created, we will have the option to attach new triggers:

[image]

On this page we just have press `+ Add trigger` button and we will have to search for DynamoDB. After we select DynamoDB, we are prompted to select our table for which we have the stream:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As I know the way that might be useful for you as well, Which is as follows.

- Open AWS Console, Search the DynamoDB service, and open it.
- Click your table and click on the triggers option.
- Then you can see the lambda's which are linked with the stream. Click on the lambda you wanna change the version/alias. Then click on the edit/test trigger button.
- You will redirect to the Lambda service page and where you can deploy your specific version of the lambda. Then stream will call that specific version of lambda.

[image]

**Short Way**:

- Open AWS Console, Search lambda service, and open your lambda/function who is trigger with the stream.
- Deploy the specific version as you need.

Hope that might be helpful for you!